# C++ Why is the uint16_t being implicitly cast to int here?

Tags: c++, gcc, casting, implicit-conversion

I have this line in my code:

```
Locus locus({track.chrom, track.begin, LOCUS_TYPE_INNER, it->left, it->right, it->gc / 5, true}) ;
```

The `it` is an iterator which points to one of these:

```
struct SimpleKmer {
    uint64_t kmer ;
    uint64_t left ;
    uint64_t right ;
    uint16_t gc ;
};
```

All the fields are unsigned. When compiling I get the following error:

```
warning: narrowing conversion of ‘(int)(((short unsigned int)((int)it.KmerIterator::operator->()->SimpleKmer::gc)) / 5)’ from ‘int’ to ‘uint16_t’ {aka ‘short unsigned int’} inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```

This concerns the `it->gc / 5` argument being passed to `Locus`. The corresponding field in `Locus` is also a `uint16_t`.

I'm confused as to why the compiler is doing all these implicit casts here. If I change the expression to `it->gc / uint16_t(5)` I still get the same error which raises the question of why the compiler is casting things to integer when they are the same type.

Does the division operator automatically cast arguments to int?

Comment: A historical artifact from C - any operator on `char` or `short` (or similar) types promote to `int`.

Comment: It's an implicit conversion, not a cast. The very definition of "cast" is "to explicitly convert". Something to keep in mind if you google stuff about these rules.

Comment: The cast you probably want isn't `it->gc / uint16_t(5)` but `uint16_t(it->gc / 5)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the division operator automatically cast arguments to int?

Promote, not cast, but yes. See [Implicit conversions: Integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) on cppreference.com:

> In particular, **[arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) do not accept types smaller than `int` as arguments**, and integral promotions are automatically applied after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable.  This conversion always preserves the value.

You are trying to assign the result of `it->gc / 5` to a `uint16_t` field, which normally isn't a problem during an assignment, eg:

```cpp
uint16_t field;
field = it->gc / 5; // OK
```

However, such a narrowing conversion from a larger integer to a smaller integer is not allowed inside of a brace initializer:

[List Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

> Narrowing conversions
>
> list-initialization limits the allowed implicit conversions by prohibiting the following:
>
> - ...
> - conversion from integer or unscoped enumeration type to integer type that cannot represent all values of the original, except where source is a constant expression whose value can be stored exactly in the target type
> - ...

A `uint16_t` can't represent all of the values of an `int`, hence the error.